# Where to put Google API PHP library for Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, google-api-php-client

I want to use the Google API PHP client library on a Wordpress site.

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

The instructions say to install the library under the "project root", but I'm not clear on what that means for a Wordpress installation. I'd certainly like to avoid having it under httpdocs; there seems to be no good reason to make the code web-visible. What is the best course?

Comment: the root of wordpress site is where all of the wp-content and wp-admin and all of that stuff live, you dont have to put that api client there...

Comment: I was hoping I didn't; there's no reason to have it web-visible, and good reasons not to. But where *should* I put it, and how do I then make it visible from Wordpress code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing:

I created a new 'libphp' directory, sibling to 'httpdocs', and put the 'google-api-php-client' under that.

Then, in the php file that needs to use the library, I did this:

```
<?php
$path = "/absolute/path/to/libphp";
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);

require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_FusiontablesService.php';
```

That worked fine, and met my goal of keeping the lib code out of the httpdocs tree. There's probably a way to add this to the global include path and hence avoid the set_include_path call, but this will do for now.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the `google-api` into a created directory such as library/includes into your theme folder and then include inside the `functions.php`

For instance in my theme directory i have a folder called lib and inside i have a `framework.php` that i house the framework i built. I simple use

`require_once locate_template( '/lib/framework.php' );`

to call on it inside the `functions.php`.

That way you can use wordpress functions along with their functions...

Comment: Interesting. It would seem odd to tie it to a particular theme; this is conceptually global resource code that could be used anywhere, not tied to my particular theme.

Comment: not following, your wordpress site uses one theme at a time? unless you are using a multi-site im not sure what you mean..

Comment: Putting things specific to my theme in the theme directory makes sense. Putting things (like the Google API client code) that are widely usable, perhaps even from php code entirely unrelated to wordpress, in a wordpress theme dir seems shortsighted. If this were Perl, I'd put it in the Perl5 library directory, or change the Perl5 lib path to point to a new directory. What's the equivalent for php? Or anybody else who's added the Google API client for php, how have you done it?

Comment: so why dont you put it in the root, and change the permissions or htaccess so nobody but you can access the folder.. meaning so they cant dig through it, if you have a problem of putting it into the theme or put the directory inside the wp-content where the plugin, uploads directories are housed.. hell you can make it into a wordpress plugin if you wanted....

Comment: Maybe I'm old-fashioned, but I object to putting library code under httpdocs. It's just the wrong thing to do. I'll find a way. Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: are you using MAMP? or XAMP? and who is everyone?

Comment: @isomeme and like i said you can make a dir inside of wp-content along with the plugins,uploads,etc if you dont like the the inside the themes folder... or inside the "public" root